# How to simplify jQuery code that uses ids and class names that include array loop indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, optimization

I have a chunk of working jQuery code (seen below) but it's very repetitive. How do I make it more simplified?

```
    $('.card-loop2').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    $('.card-loop3').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    $('.card-loop4').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');



    $('#newsUpdateLink').on( "click", function() {
        $('.category-loop1.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop2.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop3.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop4.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');

        $('.card-loop2').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.card-loop3').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.card-loop4').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    } );

    $('#categoryLink1').on( "click", function() {
        $('.category-loop1.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop1.card-loop2').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop1.card-loop3').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop1.card-loop4').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');

        $('.category-loop2').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop3').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop4').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    } );

    $('#categoryLink2').on( "click", function() {
        $('.category-loop2.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop2.card-loop2').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop2.card-loop3').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop2.card-loop4').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');

        $('.category-loop1').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop3').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop4').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    } );

    $('#categoryLink3').on( "click", function() {
        $('.category-loop3.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop3.card-loop2').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop3.card-loop3').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop3.card-loop4').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');

        $('.category-loop1').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop2').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop4').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    } );

    $('#categoryLink4').on( "click", function() {
        $('.category-loop4.card-loop1').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop4.card-loop2').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop4.card-loop3').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
        $('.category-loop4.card-loop4').addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');

        $('.category-loop1').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop2').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
        $('.category-loop3').addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
    } );
```

I've tried to do a for loop in jQuery but it did not work at all the way I was expecting.

Comment: So what exactly did the attempted `for` loops look like? Because that's clearly the right approach (or something like it).

Comment: Use a common class and `.not()`, eg `$(".card").not(".card-loop1").hide()` or `$(".card").hide();$(".card-loop1").show()` then you can replace most of the duplicated lines with a single line.   You can then also link your category via `data-` attributes, and write the whole thing using data-driven techniques, eg `$(".category").on("click", function() { $(".category-loop").not($(this).data("category")).hide() }`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a helper function like this:

```js
function updateDisplay(categorySelector, cardSelector) {
    $(categorySelector).addClass('d-flex').removeClass('d-none');
    $(cardSelector).addClass('d-none').removeClass('d-flex');
}

$('#categoryLink1').on("click", function () {
    updateDisplay('.category-loop1.card-loop1, .category-loop1.card-loop2, .category-loop1.card-loop3, .category-loop1.card-loop4', '.category-loop2, .category-loop3, .category-loop4');
});

// ... Add the rest
```

Or instead of one at a time, you could use `updateDisplay` in a for loop or a forEach. I prefer forEach:

```js
const links = ['#categoryLink1', '#categoryLink2', '#categoryLink3', '#categoryLink4'];

// Attach event handlers to category links
links.forEach(function (link, index) {
    $(link).on("click", function () {
        // use updateDisplay() with some index logic in here.
    });
});
```